# Should I store my data in JSON files or in a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I'm working on a project that uses a JavaScript framework (vis.js) to display a visual network of a certain category. There will most likely be ~2000 categories to choose from. Each category will have a sizable amount of data associated with it.

I'm wondering whether to store each category's data in an individual JSON file on the server, or to store it in a large MySQL database. Or, is there another method that you can recommend? I'm looking for efficiency of space as well as data retrieval.

Considering the front-end JavaScript needs to eventually read the data as JSON, I'm leaning towards the JSON file option, even though it seems a bit hacky. I'm interested in what the standard way(s) of doing this kind of thing, even if there are more than one.

Thanks!

Comment: What about JSON database like MongoDB or PouchDB?

Comment: _“I'm looking for efficiency of space as well as data retrieval.”_ doesn’t seem “primarily opinion-based” to me.

Comment: Dont worry, most of the time if a question cannot be answered by some code, it is put on hold...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how big the json file would be and how long it is to load for the client. Also, if its a JSON file, anybody could extract all the data, so it depends if its something important or not for you.

If you go for a DB, the advantage is to serve only the requested data asynchronously using protocole such AJAX, so probably better performance (use of indexes) and less bandwith usage.

Another avantage with the DB is that you can use its functions on server-side to mashup the data before serving it.

In conclusion, if you want something simple and portable, using JSON file is a good option. If you think your project might grow in future, using a DB probably a good option, but a little more complex though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you some no-SQL database.

most of them are really friendly to JSON and not that complex.

MongoDB is quite easy to learn, but there are others, such as:
Cassandra, Redis, DynamoDB, HBase, etc.

It depends on your demand, of course. I suggest you to look deeper into this.